# How long do sensor grenades last?

Tags: ghost-recon-future-soldier

After a while, sensor grenades seem to stop working, and I have to throw another. How long is this? It's hard for me to notice sometimes, especially in hectic situations, when it shuts off though since I might have just killed everyone there. It would be helpful if I could throw one preemptively to prevent this, but I'm not sure how long it is before they burn out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sensor grenade, after you deploy it, will last 45 seconds before it stops working according to the manual.